# Венгры и угры

Tags: этимология, топонимика

Мы знаем об угро-финской группе языков. По-украински Венгрия называется Угорщина - то есть, тоже от слова "угры". По-английски - вообще Hungary. Откуда же тогда взялось слово Венгрия? И является ли они чисто русским вариантом названия этой страны, как, например, "немцы" - русское наименование жителей Германии?

Answer (score 3):

Не чисто русским, но и польским, словенским и даже литовским и др. Венгры и угры - однокоренные слова, произошли от общего праславянского корня "огрин", далее пошли две ветки. Одна с началом на "о", "у", "я" (древне-русское "оугрин", украинское "угрин", сербское "угор", старославянское "ягрин" и др.), и вторая с началом на "в" (польское "вегьер", словенское "вогрин", литовское "ванграс" и от польского русское "венгр").